# Pass data to React component rendered server-side

Tags: express, reactjs, pug

I have a server in node.js which authenticates users by their github account credentials , if successful executes a callback and returns json data for that user and renders a jade view,

```
var reactHtml = require('./component.js');

app.get('/auth/github/callback' , function(req , res){
//get document for the user from database and store it in doc variable
res.render('index.jade' , {userName : doc.userName , reactHtml : reactHtml});
});
```

In index.jade,

```
body
 div(id='react-mount-node')!=reactHtml
```

In component.js,

```
//After requiring relevant modules

var Name = React.createClass({
render : function(){
return(<div><p>this.props.user</p></div);
});
var htmlString = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(<Name user={user}/>);
module.exports = htmlString;
```

This clearly fails as user prop is not set  , is there a way to pass the userName from the document to the react component Name ?

Is this the right way to render server side ?

If not , what would be the ideal solution ?

Comment: Have you tried exporting the `Component` only without rendering to string, then render it to string inside `app.get` ?

Comment: This was what i needed , it worked , thanks . However , if i have a large Component with several layers of nesting won't this overload the server as renderToString is called for every request ?

Comment: I don't think so if you're caching the rendered html. It's like rendering HTML with separated partials/templates. You're just rendering HTML on every request, just like in normal sites.

Comment: @MayurJoshi can you send me the snippent how you did it coz even i am struck with similar problem where i am trying to login using passport local and render the jade template where i want to set the username in the reactcomponent called in jade template